# How can I get a value from the second object that returns from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `data` object has 2 objects in each object there are multiple arrays. I want to get the value from the second object of the second array.

```
$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/First.getUniStructure',
    ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        console.log(data);

        var collage = data[0].collages[0].Name;

        console.log(collage);

        var oTable = $('#exampleTable').DataTable({

            data: data,

            columnDefs: [
                { targets: [2], data: data[0].collages[0].name }                            
            ],

            columns: [
               { data: "ID" },
               { data: "Name" },
               { data: null }
            ]

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: could you please show us what you got when you "log(data)"?

Comment: Just change `data[0]` to `data[1]`?

Comment: Please post what `data` looks like.

Comment: [Object, Object]
0
:
Object
ID
:
1
Name
:
"University Of Jordan"
collages
:
Array[1]
0
:
Object
ID
:
1
Name
:
"IT"
departments
:
Array[3]

Comment: I can get the ID and the Name but I cant get the collages array values

Comment: Collage values like this : 
[object Object]